# Is there a way to get Vue highlight in vscode using without build tools method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Vue without build tools.
When not using the build tools, you create a component like this

```
app.component('btn', {
    props: {
      text: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Button Text',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onClick() {
        this.$emit('btn-click');
      }
    },
    template: `<button @click="onClick()" class="btn btn-primary font--medium">{{ text }}</button>`,
});
```

but in visual studio code, the `template` has no highlighting. Is there an extension out there that gives this a syntax highlight?

Or is there an alternative way of creating a template?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind. I found a vscode extension that does the job.

Putting it here for others with similar problem.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=faisalhakim47.vue-inline-template